# ReactiveMongo database dump with Play Framework 2.5

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I'm trying to dump my mongo database into a json object but because my queries to the database are asynchrounous I'm having problems.

Each collection in my database contains user data and each collection name is a user name.

So, when I want to get all my users data I recover all the collection names and then loop over them to recover each collection one by one.

```
def databaseDump(prom : Promise[JsObject]) = {
    for{
      dbUsers <- getUsers
    } yield dbUsers

var rebuiltJson = Json.obj()
var array = JsArray()
res.map{ users =>
  users.map{ userNames =>
    if(userNames.size == 0){
      prom failure new Throwable("Empty database")
    }
    var counter = 0
    userNames.foreach { username =>
      getUserTables(username).map { tables =>
         /* Add data to array*/
           ...
        counter += 1
        if(counter == userNames.size){
          /*Add data to new json*/
             ...
          prom success rebuiltJson
        }

      } 
    }
  }
}
```

This kinda works, but sometimes the promise is succesfully triggered even though all the data has not yet been recoverd. This is due to that fact that my counter variable is not a reliable solution.

Is there a way to loop over all the users, query the database and wait for all the data to be recovered before succesfully triggering the promise? I tried to use for comprehension but didn't find a way to do it. Is there a way to dump a whole mongo DB into one Json : `{ username : data, username : data ..}` ?

Comment: For such db admin task, I don't think coding something new using a driver is the right way. The utility `mongodump` can directly get the data as JSON. Aside from that, I would suggest you have a look at the documentation to understand how to [find document using ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/find-documents.html), and what is the [JSON serialization](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/json/overview.html) for.

Comment: I need to do it this in scala because I am writing an API. So the data I recover is sent to other functions to be handled. I use JSON serialization but I don't see how to use it to get the whole database at once and not collection by collection.

Comment: "Dumping" is "just" a specific case of finding (all) the document of some documents (a use case, once again, is usually handled by dedicated db admin tools).

Comment: I understand that, but I would like to get my whole DB as a JsObject so that I only have to query my DB once and not multiple time. And i don't know how to do this in Scala with the reactive mongo scala driver.

Comment: There is no single operation do that, as that's not a common use case. There is operations to list the collections, and to find documents in each documents, so you can try to do it yourself.

Comment: Ok, when you say "list the collections", do you mean just the collection names or the actual collections themselves (i.e. with the data that is contained in them)?

Comment: If you have the name, you can get the collection references, from where the appropriate queries can be done. What do you have tried?

Comment: I can get all the collection names and query each collection to retreive the data. My problem is, I don't see how to wait for all the data to be retreived before continuing. In my code snippet I use a counter that is incremented every time Future.map is called. But, being asynchronus, sometimes my if case is passed and my code continues doing other things, even though all the data has not been recoverd.

Comment: I do think your questions are more related to how to work with Scala `Future` and this kind of async processing. I would suggest you have a look at some tutorials about that, as ask a precise question about, with specific code.

Comment: Ok, I originaly wanted to know if it was possible to just get all the collections at once with the reactive mongo drive. But having scimmed the documentation this seems like its not possible.

Comment: As previously said, "just get all the collections" data is not a usual driver use case

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The users/tables terminology was getting me confused, so I wrote a new function that dumps a database into a single `JsObject`.

```
// helper function to find all documents inside a collection c
// and return them as a single JsArray
def getDocs(c: JSONCollection)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = c.find(Json.obj()).cursor[JsObject]().jsArray()

def dumpToJsObject(db: DefaultDB)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[JsObject] = {
  // get a list of all collections in the db
  val collectionNames = db.collectionNames
  val collections = collectionNames.map(_.map(db.collection[JSONCollection](_)))

  // each entry is a tuple collectionName -> content (as JsArray)
  val namesToDocs = collections.flatMap {
    colls => Future.sequence(colls.map(c => getDocs(c).map(c.name -> _)))
  }

  // convert to a single JsObject
  namesToDocs.map(JsObject(_))
}
```

I haven't tested it yet (I will do so later), but this function should at least give you the general idea. You get the list of all collections inside the database. For each collection, you perform a query to get all documents inside that collection. The list of documents is converted into a `JsArray`, and finally all collections are composed to a single `JsObject` with the collection names as keys.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this but i'm getting an error with the Future.sequence part, NotInferedM[Future[NotInferedA]]. I've never used the Future.sequence function so i don't really know what this means.

Comment: As previously suggested you could have a look at tutorial or book about how [Scala Futures](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) are working

Comment: @Carsten I couldn't get your code to work but i based my solution of it. The Future.sequence function is what solved my problem in the end. I created a List[Future[JsObject]] and used Future.sequence to transform it into Future[List[JsObject]]. Then I simply looped over it.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to write the data to an output stream (local/file or network), with side effects.

```
import scala.concurrent.{ ExecutionContext, Future }
import reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocument
import reactivemongo.api.{ Cursor, MongoDriver, MongoConnection }

val mongoUri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/my_db"

val driver = new MongoDriver
val maxDocs = Int.MaxValue // max per collection

// Requires to have an ExecutionContext in the scope
// (e.g. `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`)
def dump()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Unit] = for {
  uri <- Future.fromTry(MongoConnection.parseURI(mongoUri))
  con = driver.connection(uri)
  dn <- Future(uri.db.get)
  db <- con.database(dn)
  cn <- db.collectionNames
  _  <- Future.sequence(cn.map { collName =>
    println(s"Collection: $collName")

    db.collection(collName).find(BSONDocument.empty). // findAll
      cursor[BSONDocument]().foldWhile({}, maxDocs) { (_, doc) =>
        // Replace println by appropriate side-effect
        Cursor.Cont(println(s"- ${BSONDocument pretty doc}"))
      }
  })
} yield ()
```

If using with the JSON serialization pack, just replace `BSONDocument` with `JsObject` (e.g. `BSONDocument.empty` ~> `Json.obj()`).

If testing from the Scala REPL, after having paste the previous code, it can be executed as following.

```
dump().onComplete {
  case result =>
    println(s"Dump result: $result")
    //driver.close()
}
```

Comment: I put Carsten as the solution as he replied first and both your answers are similar